# how to add dropdown menu with Cached, Similar, Share options

Tags: google, links, search, menu

Anyone please let me know, how to add similar menu in Google search result and why it is needed. Please see the below pic for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*How to add similar sites*

Google will only associate other sites with your own if theirs many websites that the website is similar too, if your site is unique or badly optimized you will not get a similar. Also for some searches it may be disabled and generally most similar are for front pages only.

*Share and search bar*

Sharing and search bar options are automated and only enabled on websites with a high volume of traffic, quality and large amounts of content.